# Logitech Gaming Software NOT Saving Custom Profiles to the On-Board Memory for their G9x Mouse on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, memory, logitech-mouse, profile

I have a Logitech G9x gaming mouse and I have Logitech Gaming Software v9.02.65 installed on my Windows 7 64-bit machine.

When I open the application and have it set to the On-Board Memory option and Select the mouse icon at the bottom of the application's interface it brings me to the User's customization page for the mouse's settings and profiles.

There are 5 available profiles that can be customized. I have set these profiles over a dozen times and every time my PC shutdowns or restarts it is not saving my profiles to the On-Board Memory.

In the past on the same OS and machine, I never had this issue. I don't know when this started for it has been quite a while... So I can not tell you if this started to occur after an update to the application, or some other changes to my PC... What I can tell you is that it's been like this for about the past 2 years now!

Does anyone know how to resolve this? What steps do I have to take to get this to work like it's supposed to, like it use to?